# HOW can i enable my "ipad" airplane mode BEFORE i unlock it?

Tags: icloud, notes.app, airplane-mode

i just read the article,

> Possible to access/restore past versions of Notes in iCloud?

And someone's answer seems great:

> Assuming you have 2 devices, let's say an iPhone and iPad, there is only one thing you can do:

```
delete something on your iPhone
as soon as you notice, enable airplane mode on your iPad
unlock iPad & open notes
copy note to somewhere else
turn off airplane mode
copy note back to notes
```

So my question is: HOW can i enable my "ipad" airplane mode BEFORE i unlock it? I didn't even know that was possible! Please help-- i need to recover my icloud note from 2 hours ago.

much appreciated!

i am rather "low-tech" BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can’t for a couple reasons.

1. Networking works while the device is locked
2. You can’t operate the device until it’s unlocked

Your best bet is to power off the device immediately and take it to where there is no WiFi to which you are pre-connected (power off that WiFi that are set up or move away from them all). Also, consider if you have cellular service, disable that or remove the SIM or go away from coverage (in a faraday cage if you can) before you unlock the device to make changes.